# VS Code Go to Matching Pair Command

Tags: visual-studio-code

This command won't work for me.  I had installed the Visual Studio Keymap, but when I uninstalled that it made no difference.  If I open Keyboard Shortcuts and try customizing it to some other keybinding, still nothing.  I open the simplest javascript folder/file (folder with a single .js file) to test, simply putting the cursor on either side of the parens in `console.log('hi');`

Version is 1.28.2 (latest).  The only other extensions I have installed are Debugger for Chrome & ESLint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`editor.action.jumpToBracket` is what you want for .js files, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd>.

The "Go to matching pair" command: `editor.emmet.action.matchTag` is for html files.

Comment: Thank.  Even the Visual Studio thought go to matching pair was the appropriate command because that command was mapped to the keys that jump to matching delimiter in Visual Studio.